# How to get onClick event on items of Toolbar while activity is using onUserInteraction()

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Is it possible to get onClick() event on items of Toolbar while activity is using onUserInteracion() method?

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is basically just a ViewGroup so we can add a TextView to it and listen to onClick events like that.

for exapmple you have a TextView to Toolbar in XML like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/tb"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:id="@+id/tb_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

on clicks listen in Activity:

```
tb.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi Mitesh, thanks for the quick reply. But when activity is overriding onUserInteraction() method, all click and touch events are getting consumed by it.